# Call a function in another html file if the condition inside of it is true

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, server

Im kind of new to coding and I have this project which is like a personal dashboard which I will show on a small screen for a raspberry pi. The dashboard just shows the current time, the temperatur and has a button for an alarm clock. And here is the problem.

I have the dashboard:
[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnXWJ.png)

"Wecker" translates to "Alarm Clock"

The button "Wecker" leads to another html file and inside of it I have some buttons with the most common times I need to wake up at:
[alarm page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKz9V.png)

When I press on a time for example 7:00 o'clock the border turns green to indicate that this is the time I want to wake up
[alarm buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im3Xz.png)

The alarm will work if the current local time hits 7:00 o'clock, the condition I wrote was to check if the border is green and if the time inside the button equals the current local time:

```
let timePickerList = document.querySelectorAll('#time_pick_1,#time_pick_2,#time_pick_3,#time_pick_4,#time_pick_5,#time_pick_6');
let timePickerArray = [...timePickerList]; //this just gets the unique id's for the buttons

var whiteStyle = "3px solid white"; //the styling for checking the condition
var greenStyle = "3px solid green"; //the styling for checking the condition

timePickerArray.forEach(function(elem) {  //the function to make the buttons have a green border if
    elem.style.border = whiteStyle;       //the border is white and make it go white if its green
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(this.style.border === whiteStyle){
            this.style.border = greenStyle;
        } else if (this.style.border === greenStyle){
            this.style.border = whiteStyle;
        }
    });
    //The function to play the alarm if the border of the element equals "greenStyle" ("3px solid green") and
    // if the current local time equals the time inside of the button. And I call this function
//every second to check this condition.
    function playAlarm(){
        var currentTimeForAlarm = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"});
        if(elem.style.border === greenStyle && currentTimeForAlarm === elem.innerHTML){
            console.log("ALARM", elem.innerHTML)
            //window.location.href = "alarmscreen.html";
            sound();
        }
    }
    setInterval(playAlarm, 1000);
})
```

**So and the problem I have is:**

How can I check this condition on the dashboard page? So I just want to click the 7:00 o'clock button, make it green and go back to the dashboard, but as soon as I go back to the dashboard the button will be white again.

I know I probably need to work with node.js or something but where do I start? Im absolutely clueless when it comes to node.js or server stuff.

Can someone maybe push me in the right direction on what to google, to save certain html styles to a server and check the condition on the server and if the condition is right call the function no matter which html page im on?

Thanks for reading, hope someone can help me :)

The Github Repo:
https://github.com/PhilipKnp/dashboard-for-raspberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the above problem write CSS classes like this

CSS:

```
.time-picker{
    border:2px solid white;
  }
.selected{
    border:  2px solid green;
}
```

and in js use localstorage to store id and content of  timepicker when class is changed.

JS:

```
var timePickerList = document.querySelectorAll('.time-picker');
//check if alarms are there in localstorage otherwise return empty array
var alarms=localStorage.getItem('alarms')? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('alarms')):[]; 
timePickerArray.forEach(function(elem) { 
       if(alarms.find( alarm => elem.id == alarm.id)){
           elem.classList.add('selected'); //if alarm contains ele id,set background green
       }
       elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
         elem.classList.toggle('selected');//
         if(elem.classList.contains('selected'))
         {
            alarms.push({id:elem.id,content:elem.innerHTML});//
            localStorage.setItem('alarms',JSON.stringify(alarms));
         } 
         else{
             let index=alarms.findIndex( alarm => alarm.id=elem.id)
            if(index!=-1){
                alarms.splice(index,1);//Remove from alarms array if alarm is disabled
                localStorage.setItem('alarms',JSON.stringify(alarms));
            }

         }
    });
})
function playAlarm(){
    let currentTimeForAlarm = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"});
    let currentAlarm=alarms.find( alarm => alarm.content == currentTimeForAlarm);
    if(currentAlarm){
        console.log(`Alarm from ${alarm.id} and content is ${alarm.content}`)
        sound();
    }
}
setInterval(playAlarm, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I used your code but it somehow won't remove the green color when I press on it again. It just stays green the whole time, but the code with the localStorage helps, maybe I can figure it out on my own.

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes kinda, when I press the button, the border turns green, and when I return to the dashboard and go to the alarm page again it still is green, but when I press on it again to make it go white, it wont stay white when I refresh the page.

Comment: oh wait localStorage.setItem('alarms',JSON.stringify(alarms)); in else part where we are doing splice.Ive updated the answer